# Factory Girl: Manipulate fields on model even when overriding that field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using Factory Girl to create model objects for my tests. I am looking to manipulate the attributes of the model even when an override is give.

Eg:

```
  factory :user, :class => User do
      domain_id 1
      email { F.generate(:email) }
      updated_at { <do some manipulation> }
  end
```

In my tests, I'm using it as follows:

```
user = F.create(:user, :updated_at => Time.now.utc)
```

This will skip the manipulation on updated_at I have in the Factory definition. Is there a way to force the manipulation even when override is provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Factorygirl callbacks:](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl)

```
factory :user, :class => User do
  domain_id 1
  email { F.generate(:email) }
  updated_at { <do some manipulation> }

  after(:create) do |user|
     #user.updated_at <do some manipulation> 
  end

  after(:build) do |user|
     <do some manipulation> 
  end
```

end

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Overridden values would be better if passed from the caller, i.e. you would pass in the overridden value when calling `F.create(:user, updated_at: overridden_value)`.

A different approach than suggested in other answer. Factory girl has `traits` that you can use for specific purpose on a factory. You could define a trait that does the manipulation for `updated_at` as follows:

```
factory :user, :class => User do
    domain_id 1
    email { F.generate(:email) }

    trait :manipulated_updated_at do
       # Manipulation code
    end
end
```

Then you'd call it as:

```
user = F.create(:user, :manipulated_updated_at, :updated_at => Time.now.utc)
```

Comment: Both great answers! Thanks!